# Taylor Series of $f(x) = e^x$ centered at $a = 3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I understand that the Taylor series for $e^x$ as a Maclaurin series is the series from $n=0$  to infinity of $x^n/n!$. With a problem like this I assumed that since it is not centered at $0,$ all you would need to change is $(x-3)^n/n!,$ but the answer is the series from $n=0$ to infinity of $e^3(x-3)^n/n!.$ I am just not sure where the $e^3$ comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have worked it like this:

$$e^x = e^3e^{x-3} = e^3 \sum_{n-0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-3)^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: Would you mind going into detail about how this works

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at $x=a$:
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2!}+ \frac{f^{(3)}(a)(x-a)^3}{3!}+\cdots.$$
What are $f(a)$, $f'(a)$, $f''(a)$, etc. for your $f(x)$ and $a$?

---

Also, what you did was replace $x$ by $x-3$ in the Taylor series for $e^x$. This means you found the Taylor series for the function you get from $e^x$ by replacing $x$ by $x-3$. That is, you found the Taylor series for $e^{x-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to start with the proper definition. In short, the taylor series for $e^x$ is not $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$, it's $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^0*x^n}{n!}$. When you center on 3 you have to change $e^0$ to $e^3$.